# React native flatlist invert order

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm making an app using react native which has a chat feature.
My FlatList is inverted, and everything is smooth as expected, except the order of messages, I want my chat (live every other chat) to show me the last messages, not the older ones.

[Screenshot of App layout with inverted messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwyBk.png)

here is my render's code:

```
<View style={styles.messages}>
     <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <FlatList
                ref={(c) => { this.flatList = c }}
                data = {this.props.messages}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                renderItem = {({item}) => 
                  <MessageRow img={item.img}  
                  msg = {item.attributes} 
                  my_user_id={this.props.my_user_id}/>
                }
                inverted
              />  
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```

Comment: Just reverse `this.props.messages`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flatlist structure items depend on your data order. What you can do is reverse messages array prop. If it comes from reducer, it should be

```
return {...state, messages: messages.reverse()}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you, i also have a problem with flatlist, when i have many messages, the last message stays behind header (i just can see it on ios due to the different scroll reaction, but only when i'm holding the screen) any advice or known bug?

Comment: i just have fixed it!

Answer (score 16):

You can try to set the props `inverted` of FlatList to be true

```
<View style={styles.messages}>
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <FlatList
            ref={(c) => { this.flatList = c }}
            data = {this.props.messages}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            inverted={true}
            renderItem = {({item}) => 
              <MessageRow img={item.img}  
                msg = {item.attributes} 
                my_user_id={this.props.my_user_id}
              />
            }
            inverted
          />  
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```

FYI, I have experience error in rendering after update `messages` if using `messages.reverse()` for the data.

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#inverted

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you need to revert the order of an array that is deep inside an object hierarchy. A parent has relatives that has children (an array):

```
const parent = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    relatives: {
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Markus'
            },
            {
                name: 'Jonas'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

if you want to update the order of **children** you need to proceed as follows:

```
const parentUpdatedClone = {
    ...parent,
    relatives: {
        ...relatives,
        children: parent.relatives.children.reverse()
    }
}
```

I hope it helps